# Is there a default block argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, groovy

I am just starting to do Groovy after mostly doing ruby.

It has a default 'block argument', `it`, as it were, not officially the terminology for Groovy, but I'm new to Groovy.

```
(1..10).each {println(it)}
```

What about Ruby? Is there a default I can use so I don't have to make `|my_block_arg|` every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have a "default" in Ruby.

Though, you can do

```
(1..10).each(&method(:puts))
```

Comment: The equivalente in Groovy would be `(1..10).each this.&println`

Answer (score 1):

Like [Andrey Deinekos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333645/3982562) explained there is no default. You can set the `self` context using [*BasicObject#instance_eval*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) or [*BasicObject#instance_exec*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec). I don't recommend doing this since it can sometimes result in some unexpected results. However if you know what you're doing the following is still an option:

```
class Enumerator
  def with_ie(&block)
    return to_enum(__method__) { each.size } unless block_given?
    each { |e| e.instance_eval(&block) }
  end
end
```

```
(1..10).each.with_ie { puts self }
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
#=> 1..10
```

```
(1..10).map.with_ie { self * self }
#=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
(-5..5).select.with_ie { positive? }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you want to call one method you might as well do `(-5..5).select(&:positive?)`, but when the objects you're iterating over have actual attributes it might be worth the trouble. For example:

```
people.map.with_ie { "#{id}: #{first_name} - #{last_name}" }
```

Keep in mind that if you have an local variable `id`, `first_name` or `last_name` in scope those are used instead of the methods on the object. This also doesn't quite work for hashes or *Enumerable* methods that pass more than one block argument. In this case `self` is set to an array containing the arguments. For example:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}.map.with_ie { self }
#=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
{a: 1, b: 2}.map.with_ie { self[0] }
#=> [:a, :b]
```

Answer (score 0):

From Ruby 2.7 onwards, you can use numbered block arguments:

```rb
(1..10).each { puts _1 }
```

Granted, this hasn't been very well documented; some references are still using `@1`, but the above is tested on the official 2.7 version.